# Regex not replacing slash in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have just created a string that should replace a word starting with `#`. I succeed in doing that but as soon as i add slash after # in the string, it does replace it. This is my code

```
 <script>
var messageString = "The folder #/folder_name was removed from the workspace #workspace_name by #user_name"
result = messageString.replace(/#(\w+)/g, function(_, $1) { return " HELLO"; })
alert(result );
</script>
```

My question is why its not working when i add a slash after the # and how can i replace the word which has / also. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the slash as part of the valid characters to match, one way is to use `[\/]` along with the rest of the characters, will look like:

```
messageString.replace(/#([\/\w]+)/g,
```

Keep in mind that **`\w`** means `[a-zA-Z_]`

For example `[\/\w]+` is equal too `[\/a-zA-Z_]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
result = messageString.replace(/#(\S+)/g, function(_, $1) { return " HELLO"; })
```

`\w` is a word character that doesn't match `/` hence your regex is failing. `\S`, in contrast will match any non-space character.